# Export PageSpeed Insights (by Google) results

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, frontend, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

Is there any way to export PageSpeed (the Google Chrome extension) results into a file?
I'm looking for a way to export the results from web-site testing using PageSpeed tab in the browser console.

Comment: This is exactly what i'm looking for. Either EXPORT (or) SAVE feature is really required.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you open up and run Google PageSpeed Insights through the **Audit** tab (**Lighthouse** tab after Chrome 83) in **Chrome Developer Tools**, there is a button in the left part of the panel that will allow you to download the report as a JSON file.

[image: Google PageSpeed Insights Audit Report]

Answer (score 6):

From my understanding, Tom's answer is missing some context and depending on your use case, can give the wrong impression.

Chrome's performance throttling is RELATIVE to the machine running the
audit.  So that means running an audit on a weaker machine is going to
give an artificially lower score than what it may actually be on another machine.

PageSpeed Insights (PSI) runs a lighthouse audit on a [simulated Moto 4](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/about?hl=en-US&utm_source=PSI&utm_medium=incoming-link&utm_campaign=PSI#faq).

> What device and network conditions does Lighthouse use to simulate a page load?
>
> Currently, Lighthouse simulates a page load on a mid-tier device (Moto G4) on a mobile network.

So if you run an audit through the Chrome tab on a 2018 Macbook Pro and your client runs it on a 2010 HP laptop, you will get vastly different results.  So using PSI should give a more "objective" audit as it's using the same hardware for each test.

If you only ever use your development machine to run tests for yourself, then it may not matter as much.  But if you are sharing and cross examining reports with a client or team (across different machines), then this is something to keep in mind.

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference

> Throttling is relative to your computer's capabilities. For example,
> the 2x slowdown option makes your CPU operate 2 times slower than its
> usual ability. DevTools can't truly simulate the CPUs of mobile
> devices, because the architecture of mobile devices is very different
> from that of desktops and laptops.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but I feel you can build the data you need using the JSON response

```
curl https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=http://www.google.com > response.json
```

If you don't have access to cli you can enter the same url with your website of interest in your browser and hit return key.

I lately started using Postman if you are trying to optimize your website performance I personally feel this would help because it does save the responses and the time of request.

Thank you it was helpful

Comment: I might be wrong, I was answering about [link](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) and not the extension